# Runtime 9 Error when adding worksheets from a list of files

Tags: excel, vba

I currently am having difficulty with some Excel VBA Code, my problem occurs when adding sheets to a workbook when looping through some code.

```
Dim DFWB As Workbook      'Dailyfeed Workbook
  Dim NewWb As Workbook     'New Data sheet for all linked Ip addresess
  Dim DataWb As Workbook
  Dim NewWbs As Worksheet
  Dim rtable As Range, Flist As Worksheet


    Set DFWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set Flist = DFWB.Worksheets("File List")

    'Open New Workbook for data
    Set NewWb = Workbooks.Add(Template:=xlWBATWorksheet)

    For i = 2 To Flist.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


        thisfile = Flist.Cells(i, 1)
        If thisfile = "" Then Exit For
        Set DataWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=thisfile)
        DFWB.Activate
        DR = ActiveCell.Value
        DataWb.Activate
        Set DataWbs = ActiveSheet
        DataWbs.Activate
        If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If
    End If
    'Get data from DataWbs Worksheet
        DataWbs.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=WorksheetFunction.Match("IPAddr", DataWbs.Range("1:1"), 0), Criteria1:=DR, Operator:= _
        xlAnd
        Set rtable = DataWbs.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
       NewWb.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(NewWb.Sheets.Count)
       Set NewWbs = NewWb.Worksheets(NewWb.Sheets.Count)
        NewWbs.Cells(1, 4).Value = thisfile
        NewWbs.Cells(1, 3).Value = "IP Data From File"
        rtable.Copy Destination:=NewWbs.Cells(3, 1)
        With NewWbs.Range("C1:D1").Font
            .FontStyle = "Bold"
            .Size = 16
        End With
        NewWbs.Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 18
        NewWbs.Columns(2).ColumnWidth = 14
        NewWbs.Columns(3).ColumnWidth = 30

        DataWb.Activate
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If
    End If
    ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=False

    Next i
    NewWb.Activate
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    NewWb.Worksheets(1).Activate

   End Sub
```

I get runtime error 9 at the following line of code that adds the new new sheet.

```
      NewWb.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(NewWb.Sheets.Count)
   Set NewWbs = NewWb.Worksheets(NewWb.Sheets.Count)
```

My code works for the 1st two files in my list but not any more, does anyone have any ideas.

Comment: Please add error details

Answer (score 0):

Morning,

The error occurs when trying to add the 3rd worksheet to accept the copied data. The error comes up with "subscript out of range" runtime error 9

Does the fact that it works twice, when debugging it opens the data workbook, identifies the data, selects the range. It will just not add the new worksheet to paste the data.

Could a way round this be for the Filelist variable count the number of files in the list then add the correct number is sheets to the new workbook then just use a loop to copy and paste the data across the sheets.